# why are some of my site's elements positioned differently across multiple browsers?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

site in progress: http://www.modernfuture.net/wordpress

my site is finally looking and behaving as expected in Firefox 23!

However if I view the site in Chrome 29, or Safari 5, my social div, logo image, and featured post image are positioned differently than expected.

Any thoughts on what's causing this?

Also this site looks completely different than expected on my Galaxy S3 but I should probably save this question for a different thread. Either way not sure if it has something to do with this cross-browser funkiness or not but thought I should mention it regardless.

Thanks for your help SO!!

Comment: Here's the solution to the issue! Thank you SO!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625162/modifying-a-class-generated-in-php-across-multiple-browsers-using-css

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS reset and it will minimalize the differences between browsers.

Here is an [example](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: I believe I have one of those going on already if I'm not mistaken. It's called normalize https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css Thanks for your reply though :)

Answer (score 1):

The layout seems to be based on a really funky set of relative positioning without a solid base. For instance, the header's pieces could be made into `inline-block` elements and vertically aligned before fine-tuning with `position:relative;`

Comment: The base I thought I was building the site around was the body tag...who's position is static I think...wouldn't this be solid grounds to have all it's hierarchical children be positioned relatively to? But I like your idea about inline-block on all header elements - but I don't see right away how that will help. Could you explain more please? Thank you!!

Comment: By default the body is static, but each new element you add can affect the way the elements naturally stack, which can vary by browser. Using `position:relative;` moves elements from that resting place, so if the elements originally rested in different places from one browser to the next, their *moved* location will also be different.

I think what you mean to do/thought you did was to use `position:absolute;` - which would base everything on the top-left corner of the page regardless of their natural stacking order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I should stay away from absolute positioning. However I did manage to find a fix for two of the three elements that needed cross-browser fixing by using the following hack: @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}  however this doesn't work with the third one because, and I'm just guessing here, it's a class generated from within the loop - any thoughts on this?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is the way you're using so much positioning is just really getting in the way of things that would otherwise be fairly simple.

For example, your featured post title and its image can be put where you want them just by doing `float:right;margin:15px;` on the title and `float:left;margin:15px;` on the image.

Comment: David I _completely_ agree with what you're saying. I wish I were better at PHP so I could make that happen (those elements you speak of are generated inside of the Wordpress loop.) For now I'm hoping I can make what I have work out so I don't have to dig more into the PHP side of things. But I really appreciate your very insightful and thoughtful dialog on this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Floats are CSS - it wouldn't involve modifying *any* PHP.