# modifying a class generated in PHP across multiple browsers using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

site in progress: http://www.modernfuture.net/wordpress

I've been trying to maintain cross-browser continuity and I came across a media query hack that targets chrome 1+/safari 3+

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
/* ... */
}
```

I've used this to restyle #social .logo-img and .featuredThumb differently in chrome/safari as they were positioning these elements differently than in Firefox 23. Using this awesome bit of code I was able to restyle #social, and .logo-img but not .featuredThumb. My guess for the cause of this is that the .featuredThumb class was generated in PHP but I'm not sure *why* this is happening.

Here's the piece of PHP code that's generating the .featuredThumb class

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(287,250), array('class' => 'featuredThumb')); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
```

I could really use some assistance with this matter please! Thank you all!!

Comment: It doesn't mind if the class is generated using PHP, because the client only receives html.

Comment: can you tell us where we can find the .featuredThumb class on your page to inspect? thanks

Comment: Oriol, I thought that would be true (it was only my best guess). Yet this problem still exists...any clue why? Thanks!

Comment: .featuredThumb class modifies the look of the featured post image. Should be visible in the upper middle of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
top: 92px;
```

to:

```
top: -92px;
```

that works for me. Not sure if this is what youre after :/

Comment: Although, even if you fix your layout in this way, you might want to look at a different way to position your elements. Your layout will break if you have a title with only one line of text or with more than 2 lines of text.